# C++ How can I redirect STDIN to a function

Tags: c++, cross-platform, std, iostream, stdio

I've spent some time researching for a way to redirect STDOUT and STDIN to functions.

While I eventually found and succeeded at redirecting STDOUT to a callback, I'm unable to redirect STDIN to a callback too (I can't find any resources except for redirecting STDIN to files).

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I made a custom console with windows forms and I've connected it with pipes to my main program. I can already print and read from it using this:

```
Console::PrintLn("Hello World!");
std::string in;
Console::ReadLn(in);
```

But my goal was to use for example this:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str; // Read string from custom console
std::cout << str << std::endl; // Print string to custom console
std::printf("Hi!"); // It should also work with printf
```

Comment: What do you mean _"redirect"_?? Can't you just use `STDOUT` and `STDIN` in your functions?

Comment: I have clarified my question, sorry.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "just use STDOUT and STDIN in your functions". Could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to do this in a cross-platform manner. On a Unix box I would create a `socketpair` and use `dup2` to set fd 0 and 1 to one end. Then I'd run the console on a separate thread and have it read and write from the other end.

Comment: I'm using Windows at the moment, so if there isn't a cross-platform way to do it, I would prefer to use Windows by now.

Comment: @RicardoAntunes How would you intend to use it without a function?

Comment: I intend to use for example std::scanf and std::printf instead of using my own class functions (redirecting std::scanf and std::printf to those functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't believe you can do this in a cross-platform way.

Essentially what you want to do is replace `stdin` and `stdout` with something that instead of actually doing input and output, calls your console input and output routines.

This, mostly, isn't exactly possible. Part of the reason why is that even if you replace stdin and stdout it will not be enough. There may be parts of the program that try to manipulate stdin and stdout in an even more direct fashion.

On a Unix system I would solve this with threads and pipes or socketpairs. Then I would use the `dup2` system call to replace file descriptors 0 and 1. That would make sure that no program could bypass your console unless it tried extremely hard (basically it would have to open `/dev/tty` and output to that on purpose).

On Windows, I have no idea what I'd do to solve this problem in a complete way. You could try using `freopen`, to replace `stdin` and `stdout`. That will work for most code because it will use the standard library calls. And `cin` and `cout` are supposed to actually use C stdio underneath so that they're interoperable with C code that may be running on another thread.

I'm not sure if a `FILE *` in the Visual C/C++ version the `stdio` library contains anything that would let you redirect IO to callbacks, so you'd probably still have to somehow use the Windows equivalent of pipes to make this work.

If you just want to replace `cout` and `cin` that's probably doable by replacing their `streambuf` objects with your own. I'm not exactly sure how to make this work, but I think you should look at the [`rdbuf` member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) of the `cin` and `cout` objects.

Implementing your own `streambuf` isn't hard. I just had to do this myself. Unfortunately, even though the code contains nothing particularly specific to any of the details of what I'm working on here, the code is still proprietary, so I can't paste it. But there are a number of examples of this in the [various code samples from a Josuttis book on the C++ standard library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/io/).

For your particular case, you could likely get away with a streambuf of your own that just overloaded the [`underflow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/underflow) (for input) and [`overflow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) (for output) functions and had a completely unbuffered streambuf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to what you said I'm seeing I will have trouble implementing what I want with STDIN and STDOUT, so what about redirecting just std::cout and std::cin?

Comment: @RicardoAntunes: Updated with how to do `cout` and `cin`.

Comment: @RicardoAntunes: And, a little more detail. :-)